# How do I write an HTTP server in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, cpan

Is there a webserver or HTTP server module in the Perl standard library or in CPAN or elsewhere?  I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of Python 3's `http.server` module.  Thanks!

Comment: :) I posted the answer 10 minutes before you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1899431/list

Comment: What for? Is this an http server just to be an http server, or is this an http server in order to do `X`? Knowing either or what X is might lead to more relevant answers.

Comment: Usually this comes up because I want to slap some kind of crappy UI or API on some prototype or throwaway thing, and wrapping an HTTP server around it seems like it might be an expedient option, depending.  I certainly got the answers I was hoping for!

Comment: Curiously, the answers so far point you to the same moudles you would have found by searching "http server" at http://search.cpan.org . At least make it look like you're trying to do your own work. :)

Comment: @zaphod => if your goal is to mock up quick gui's via http, take a look at XUL::Gui which does just that

Comment: I swear I looked at CPAN first.  I made the mistake of clicking on the "Networking Devices IPC" category and carefully reading the resulting list, which turned up nothing remotely useful.  Then I tried "man perlmodlib".  Then I gave up and asked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Daemon), I would recommend taking a look at [HTTP::Server::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Server::Simple) which indeed is very easy to use.

Comment: I've stability issues with HTTP::Server::Simple when running for a long time (several days), but I've had better success with HTTP::Server::Simple w/ Net::Server::PreFork

Comment: @mpeters: I use HTTP::Server::Simple for applications that run for a few hours at a time so did not notice such problems but thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 5):

See [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=http%3A%3Adaemon&mode=all)

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few more:

- [Catalyst::Engine::HTTP](http://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Engine::HTTP)
- [Net::Server](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server)