# how to parse request URL in simple server in Perl which listen to port

Tags: perl

here is the request URL http://localhost:9009/?comd&user=kkc&mail=kkc@kkc.com

what are the modification need to do in the server perl script.

### server-Perl-script

```
use IO::Socket;
use Net::hostent;       # for OO version of gethostbyaddr
$PORT = 9009;           # pick something not in use
$server = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto     => 'tcp',
                                 LocalPort => $PORT,
                                 Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
                                 Reuse     => 1);

die "can't setup server" unless $server;
print "[Server $0 accepting clients]\n";
     while ($client = $server->accept()) 
     {
       $client->autoflush(1);
       print $client "Welcome to $0; type help for command list.\n";
       $hostinfo = gethostbyaddr($client->peeraddr);
       printf "[Connect from %s]\n", $hostinfo ? $hostinfo->name : $client->peerhost;
       print $client "Command? ";
       while ( <$client>) {
         next unless /\S/;       # blank line
            if (/comd/i )        { print  $client `dir`;      }
       } continue {
          print $client "Command? ";
       }
       close $client;
       print "client closed";
     }
```

Comment: Start by using an HTTP server instead of a raw socket.

Comment: [These answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904420/how-do-i-write-an-http-server-in-perl) probably show a better way to build an HTTP server in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your script is not for production, but for homework or testing sometime. There are multiple very efficient web server solutions in/with Perl like [Apache](http://www.apache.org) with CGIs or mod_perl, [HTTP::Server::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Server::Simple) and [PSGI/Plack](http://www.plackperl.org).

You'll also typically use a framework like [Dancer](http://perldancer.org), [Mojo](http://mojolicious.org/) or [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) which does most of the boring standard stuff for you:

```
use Dancer;

get '/' => sub {
    return 'Hi there, you just visited host '.request->host.
        ' at port '.request->port.' asking for '.request->uri;
};
```

Back to your question: Your script is a interactive server while HTTP has a strict request and response structure:

1. Client connects to server
2. Client sends a request
3. Server sends a response

You need to remove the interactive part and just wait for the client to start the conversation:

```
use IO::Socket;
use Net::hostent;       # for OO version of gethostbyaddr
$PORT = 9009;           # pick something not in use
$server = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto     => 'tcp',
                                 LocalPort => $PORT,
                                 Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
                                 Reuse     => 1);

die "can't setup server" unless $server;
print "[Server $0 accepting clients]\n";
     while ($client = $server->accept()) 
     {
       $hostinfo = gethostbyaddr($client->peeraddr);

       # Read request up to a empty line
       my $request;
       while ( <$client>) {
         last unless /\S/;
         $request .= $_;
       }

       # Do something with the request

       # Send response
       print $client "Status: 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n".$request;

       close $client;
       print "client closed";
     }
```

The server reads the full request from the client and returns a minimized HTTP header plus the original request.